# Keras Conv2D with extended Batch Shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, convolution

Hello I am trying to use the last example from keras [Conv2D](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)

```
# With extended batch shape [4, 7]:  
import tensorflow as tf
input_shape = (4, 7, 127, 127, 3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[2:])(x)
print(y.shape)
```

However I am getting a shape error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_11 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [4, 7, 127, 127, 3]
```

Comment: What do you mean by extended batch shape? are you feeding in a batch of videos?

Comment: My batches are sequences of images captured from different views. you can consider them as videos. my intended shape in the model summary would be `(BS, SEQ, IMG_W ,IMG_H, CH)`

Comment: The example you are referring to uses tensorflow version 2.3.0, so you probably need to update tensorflow.

Comment: @aiguy990 - Yes, I agree with GentlemanJenkins and I just verified that it runs fine in 2.3.0